# Logical notation in Ultraproducts Section of Book $\lambda i$. What does it mean?

Tags: logic, notation, definition, model-theory

Does anyone understand the notation $\lambda i$ circled in this image?

[image]

It is found in [Logic and Structure By Dirk van Dalen](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Logic_and_Structure/Ql3xCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), in the section on `Ultraproducts`. I can't find any clue as to what that notation is.

Comment: As mentioned by DavidW below, this notation comes from $\lambda$-calculus. In general, I wouldn't recommend using Van Dalen's book unless absolutely necessary: the exposition is often too terse/obscure, and the book has a lot of "hidden prerequisites" like this one.

Comment: See van Dalen, page 222.

Comment: If $\cdots i\cdots$ is some expression involving a variable $i$, then $\lambda i.\,\cdots i\cdots$ denotes the function whose value at any $i$ is $\cdots i\cdots$. Most mathematicians are more likely to write $i\mapsto \cdots i\cdots$ for this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a lambda-abstraction in the lambda calculus that was introduced by Alonzo Church. It is a way of writing an anonymous function. For example $\lambda i. M$ is an abstraction that can be applied to an argument $N$, so that $N$ replaces every free occurrence of $i$ in $M$. That operation is called $\beta$-reduction. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus as a start.